# Why I cannot see data in hierarchy table?

Tags: html, vue.js, tree, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to create a hierarchical table in Vue.js, this should be such a base therefore. However, I don't want to show the table with the data. The error would be here:
`<tr v-if="item.childrenVisible" v-for="child in item.children" :key="child.id">`
If I remove this whole section, I can see the table

**HTML:**

```
    <table>

      <thead>
        
        <tr>

          <th>Name</th>

          <th>Parent</th>

          <th>Actions</th>

        </tr>

      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">

          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>

          <td>{{ item.parent }}</td>

          <td>

            <button @click="toggleChildren(item)">Toggle Children</button>

          </td>

          <tr v-if="item.childrenVisible" v-for="child in item.children" :key="child.id">

            <td>{{ child.name }}</td>

            <td>{{ child.parent }}</td>

            <td>

              <button @click="toggleChildren(child)">Toggle Children</button>

            </td>

          </tr>

        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
```

**Vue.js script and my whole mini-project:**
https://jsfiddle.net/barabas/jrcufeah/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was you cannot use v-if and v-for on the same node like I did so this is how I fix it

```
<template v-if="item.childrenVisible">
              <tr v-for="child in item.children" :key="child.id">
                <td>{{ child.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ child.parent }}</td>
                <td>
                  <button @click="toggleChildren(child)">Toggle Children</button>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </template>
```

I split up the `v-for` and `v-if` to two different node `template` and `tr`